# In C#, how do I resolve the IP address of a host?

Tags: c#, ip-address, resolve

How can you dynamically get the IP address of the server (PC which you want to connect to)?

Comment: As an example, Ping.Send requires an IPAddress, so for "server is alive" validation code it needs translation.

Answer (score 17):

[System.Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostentry.aspx) can be used to resolve a name to an IP address.

Answer (score 10):

```
IPHostEntry Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(DNSNameString);
DoSomethingWith(Host.AddressList);
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help but I want to get the visitor's IP address not the pc im working on

Comment: Erm.  My example is nothing to do with the PC you're on.  DNSNameString is meant to be the name of the server you're connecting to -- that is, answering the original question.  I don't know where this stuff you're saying about a visitor's IP address comes from or what it has to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you Use the Below Method you will be able to resolve correctly

```
 public static bool GetResolvedConnecionIPAddress(string serverNameOrURL, out IPAddress resolvedIPAddress)
        {
            bool isResolved = false;
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;
            IPAddress resolvIP = null;
            try
            {
                if (!IPAddress.TryParse(serverNameOrURL, out resolvIP))
                {
                    hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(serverNameOrURL);

                    if (hostEntry != null && hostEntry.AddressList != null && hostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (hostEntry.AddressList.Length == 1)
                        {
                            resolvIP = hostEntry.AddressList[0];
                            isResolved = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (IPAddress var in hostEntry.AddressList)
                            {
                                if (var.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                                {
                                    resolvIP = var;
                                    isResolved = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    isResolved = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                resolvedIPAddress = resolvIP;
            }

            return isResolved;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do an nslookup.

Here's an example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DougBell/NSLookUpDB00112052005013753AM/NSLookUpDB001.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on chaos's answer, you don't want the IP address of a server, you want the IP address of a client.  If that's the case, fix your question ... and your answer would be HttpRequest.UserHostAddress.