# how to convert ip address to url with VB.NET OR C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, url, ip-address

I want to convert ip address to url. But i can't figure it out how to.

Comment: There's no conversion from an ip address to an url. Maybe there's a "conversion" from an ip address to a domain name, aka. reverse dns. Maybe; it depends on the dns server responsible for the ip address

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, how do I resolve the IP address of a host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029749/in-c-how-do-i-resolve-the-ip-address-of-a-host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibility of multiple website hosted on single IP. But you can get default using

```
 IPHostEntry IpEntry = Dns.GetHostByAddress(ip); 
 return iphostentry.HostName.ToString();
```

Following might helpful to start with:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/uchukamen/IPAddHostConverter12052005041212AM/IPAddHostConverter.aspx

Comment: @m.qayyum: Note that this is basically the same as my answer, except that `GetHostByAddress` is now obsolete - `GetHostEntry` is the preferred method now.

Comment: @Jon - Yes, it is same answer but see the time when it is posted. When I opened page, I could not see your comment and replied bit late. That is the reason i missed it.

Comment: But my point is that there's still no benefit in using a deprecated API when there's another available...

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear what you want - an example would have been helpful - but something as simple as:

```
string url = "http://" + ipAddress;
```

would quite possibly be enough.

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like you're trying to find the *name* for an IP address. In some ways that's quite simple:

```
IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry("72.29.94.50");
Console.WriteLine(entry.HostName);
```

However, this *doesn't* print eggheadcafe.com. It prints something entirely different:

```
72.29.94.50.static.dimenoc.com
```

That's entirely correct in terms of a reverse DNS lookup (run "nslookup 72.29.94.50" to see the same result)... but it's not what you were looking for.

The problem is that I believe this eggheadcafe.com is served by virtual hosting - although eggheadcafe.com *is* served on that IP address, so are other websites (at least potentially). When you visit eggheadcafe.com in your browser, it resolves to that IP address but *also* specifies the host name in an HTTP header.

Comment: I want to convert an ip address to it's url. as 72.29.94.50 to http://www.eggheadcafe.com

Comment: I guess @m.qayyum is talking about DNS resolving

Comment: @abatishchev: Sounds like it, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you want to achieve but guess you need to resolve a host name from IP.

In this case you can use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997.aspx) method.